# Por que meu try/catch só aceita "Exception e" (Genérico)?

Tags: java, exceção, io

Quero especificar as exceptions, não dessa forma generalizada porém o `item.write` só aceita `Exception e`

```
public File saveFile(FileItem item, File dirFile, String filename) {
        dirFile.mkdirs();
        File file = FileUtils.getFile(dirFile, filename);
        try {
            item.write(file);
            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Boa atitude. Qual exceção você quer especificar? E o que acontece quando faz isto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Na verdade o seu *try-catch* aceita sim outros tipos de exceção, mais específicos**, mas você não escapará de ter que tratar também o tipo mais genérico *Exception* ou de ter que adicioná-lo na declaração do método.

## Isto ocorre por estes dois motivos:

### 1) O Java tem uma coisa chamada *checked exceptions*

A idéia de uma *checked exception* é avisar o consumidor de um método, através da assinatura do método, quais exceções aquele código pode lançar, assim o consumidor precisa explicitamente decidir o que fazer com aquelas exceções.

As opções do consumidor de um método que declara *checked exceptions* são:

**a)** Capturar a exceção e fazer algo com ela:

```
public void facaAlgo() {
    try {
        MetodoQueLancaCertaCheckedException();
    } catch (CertaCheckedException e) {
        // ...faz algo útil com a exceção
    }
}
```

**b)** Não fazer nada com a exceção e deixar ela propogar. Neste caso, o consumidor precisa ele próprio declarar aquela mesma exceção na sua própria assinatura como sendo uma checked exception:

```
public void facaAlgo() throws CertaCheckedException {
    MetodoQueLancaCertaCheckedException();
}
```

Agora o consumidor do método *facaAlgo* também terá que ou capturar a exceção ou redeclará-la na sua própria assinatura.

### 2) O desenvolvedor da classe FileItem foi relaxado

Este é o segundo motivo para você ser obrigada a ou capturar a exceção genérica *Exception* ou redeclará-la na assinatura do seu método.

Esta classe pertence à biblioteca *apache-commons*. Quem fez esta classe, ou precisamente este método, decidiu não ter que decidir quais exceções declarar e declarou a mais genérica. Todos os demais métodos da classe lançam exceções mais expecíficas.

## Como você pode tratar uma exceção mais específica

Então você já notou que este método pode disparar exceções mais específicas, como de *IO*, e quer dar um tratamento diferenciado a esta exceção. **Yes, you can!**

Embora você não escape de ter que fazer algo com a *Exception*, você pode fazer o que precisa com a exceção mais específica. Se você não quer declarar *checked exceptions* para o consumidor do seu código, faça assim:

```
public File saveFile(FileItem item, File dirFile, String filename) {
    dirFile.mkdirs();
    File file = null;
    try {
        item.write(file);
        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ... tratamento específico para estes tipos de exceção
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Ou, se você deseja ou não se importa de ter *Exception* como uma *checked exception* do seu método, faça assim:

```
public File saveFile(FileItem item, File dirFile, String filename) throws Exception {
    dirFile.mkdirs();
    File file = null;
    try {
        item.write(file);
        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ... tratamento específico para estes tipos de exceção
    }
}
```

## Conclusão

O seu `try-catch` **aceita** outros tipos que não *Exception* mas, devido a uma decisão (provavelmente ruim) do desenvolvedor do método *FileItem.write*, você precisará tratar *Exception* **também** além de tratar a exceção mais específica que deseja.

Answer (score 7):

Segundo o [javadoc da classe FileItem](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#write(java.io.File)), esse é o comportamento esperado, pois ele só envia uma `Exception` quando um erro ocorre, sem um tipo mais específico de objeto.

Resumindo, você pode tratar a `Exception` lançando um tipo diferente, mas ainda assim, será um lançamento genérico de erro.

Comment: Estou pesquisando mais antes de votar mas parece ser isto mesmo. Java me decepciona cada dia mais. Aí não dá para ensinar os programadores programarem organizadamente quando a API exige programar de qualquer jeito.

Comment: Fato. A Apache tem muita coisa boa, mas essa API de arquivos ai deixou a desejar nesse ponto. D: